Where does the name of the `pure` function in the `Applicative` type class come from?
At this point in my learning journey, I simply accepted that this function is called pure (both in Haskell and in PureScript), but it would have helped a lot if I had known the reasoning behind this name.
Both the Haskell reference and the PureScript docs use the word "lift",

Haskell Lift a value into the Structure.

PureScript pure can be seen as the function which lifts functions of zero arguments

but lift is already in use (e.g., for monad transformersHaskell, Purescript).
The PureScript reference for pure also uses the word "wrap", but I understand now why the functor explanations along the lines of "wrap value in a box" can be misleading or miss the point entirely. For these reasons, I do like the name pure as it has no "baggage" and I can focus on understanding the topic without preconceptions.
Books and tutorials using the word "context" helped me understand the more abstract constructs, so I sometimes wondered if using "embed" would make sense here, but then I let it go.

Anyway, I still research from time to time to figure out pure's etymology, but did not get any closer yet.

"Pure" is in contrast to "effectful", as in "pure functional programming". pure x embeds a pure value x into an effectful computation that does not have any effects.

The original paper which introduced applicative functors is very readable https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming/article/applicative-programming-with-effects/C80616ACD5687ABDC86D2B341E83D298 and in section 2 gives a rationale for the "pure" name: "The idea is that pure embeds pure computations into the pure fragment of an effectful world – the resulting computations may thus be shunted around freely, as long as the order of the genuinely effectful computations is preserved."

@NaïmFavier That should be an answer, not a comment!

@danidiaz Same to you. And in case length is what's stopping (either of) you, answers don't have to be long to be useful.

Thank you, Naïm Favier, that is excellently put, and thank you danidiaz for the origin paper! If both of you posted an answer, I would accept Naïm's (being the first commenter), but I would definitely upvote both. (I thought about making a community answer, but I don't want to rob neither of you of reputation.)
